# How to send push messages to Android endpoint https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send without user keys

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging, web-push

We are receiving https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send as endpoint when some android users registers to receive push messages.
Problem is the registration info we get comes with no keys.

On most of the clients we get the last endpoint (https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send) with keys so we can send notifications with no problem.

Is there a way to send push notifications to the android.googleapis.com/gcm/send endpoint with no user keys?

Some user agent examples where we get no keys are:

- Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.4.4; XT1032 Build/KXB21.14-L1.40) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.91 Mobile Safari/537.36
- Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0.1; Z981 Build/MMB29M) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.91 Mobile Safari/537.36

Comment: you might be wasting your time implementing this. The GCM endpoints will be removed in april

Comment: We do know that, but would like to manage these users somehow so they can receive notifications until then, and if possible "migrate" their endpoints somehow to FCM

Comment: Same issue here, I currently assume that these users have old devices which do not support web push and thereby will always deliver a gcm subscription.